# Should I be parsing and creating CSV files on the client (React.js)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv

I'm using React.js on the client and a GraphQL Apollo server with TypeScript.

JavaScript and React are a powerful combination and I could almost write the entire app in-browser (save the database).

I understand the use cases where I need to have business logic on the server. This includes calculations and extension data manipulation.

With this in mind, should I be parsing and creating CSV files on the client? At the moment, I am reading in CSV files on the client and sending the data to my server to be parsed before being sent back. Users can then preview the data import and decide if they want to upload it.

When exporting data to CSV, at first it was simple because I had a JSON and converted it into a simple CSV using json2csv (npm module). But now I'm taking object accessors and converting them to Titles which include readable English and a tag used for data imports (i.e. 'libraryBookTitle' becomes 'Library Book Title [libraryBookTitle]'). I'm also parsing the data to remove unwanted columns as well as re-ordering the order. I'm also exporting 4 different data types. This means I need large configuration objects just for exporting data to CSV.

So I'm thinking it might be better to do this on the server. Thoughts? The thing is that I like having instant exports on the browser because of the user experience.